# How to stop Amazon EBS charge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I created some EBS volumes on some Linux instances. Then I terminated the instances but the volumes were still there (I forgot to check the *Delete on Termination* setting).

When I went to billing I saw that I was charged for the IOPS of those EBS volumes -- approximately US$8. So then I removed them, even though they were no longer attached to the instances (they were just there but with an *available* state).

Today after almost a day without EBS volumes in my AWS account I see that the billing is US$13!!! I checked the billing details and it all charged to IOPS of the EBS volumes even though I already removed them yesterday! I need to stop this right away.

I opened a case yesterday in AWS and the case is still unassigned. Anybody knows how EBS volumes are being charged? HELP! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes AWS support takes some time to get back to you, this depends on your support level. If you have the free tier it may take 48 hours.

EBS is charged monthly and the charges do not instantly show up. So more than likely the $8-$13 charge was already there when you terminated the volumes.

You can view the EBS pricing here: https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/

Comment: yes that was it. The delay till charge was updated between ebs volume was created and then  was removed. thnaks